# Empty raster returned after GRASS i.atcorr with Landsat8 data

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, imagery, landsat-8

I've searched at length on previous forums but no solution seems to work for me.

I'm trying to run the i.atcorr module on GRASS (version 6.4.3 on a Macbook Pro, Mavericks OSX) with Landsat8 imagery.

Parameters didn't seem to be loading from the provided metadata file (MTL_txt), so I went back to the GRASS manuals and tried to input values by hand, here is what I used:

8 = geometrical conditions=Landsat ETM+

05 04 03.81  98.117 23.131 = month day hh.ddd longitude latitude ("hh.ddd" is in GMT decimal hours)

1 = atmospheric mode=tropical

0 = aerosols model=none (ASSUMING NO AEROSOLS)

0 = visibility [km]

0.732 = aerosol optical depth 550 nm

-1.408 = mean target elevation above sea level [km]

-1000 = sensor on board a satellite

0 = THIS IS WHAT I'M WORRIED ABOUT: There is no pre-defined coding for Landsat 8 satellites and I am unsure how to define my own spectral conditions??

I checked I was in the correct region (i.e. used g.region) and I've tried using both radiance and reflectance at sensor values (computed using i.landsat.toar, which seems to have worked nicely) but the rasters returned are empty :(

**Here is what I'm running (in verbose)**

i.atcorr -a --overwrite --verbose iimg=Part1toar_B1@Charlie icnd=/Users/charlottewhitham/Documents/PhD/My research/my GIS/grassdata/NGH/Charlie/.tmp/Charlie.local/819.2 oimg=P1toar_atcorrB1
* ****************************** 6s version 4.2b

---

- geometrical conditions identity
  *
- -------------------------------
  *
- etm+     observation
  *
  *
  *
- month: 5 day: 4
  *
- solar zenith angle:   23.55 deg  solar azimuthal angle:
  103.24 deg   *
- view zenith angle:     0.00 deg  view azimuthal angle:
  0.00 deg   *
- scattering angle:    156.45 deg  azimuthal angle
  difference: 103.24 deg   *
  *
  *
- atmospheric model description
  *
- -----------------------------
  *
- atmospheric model identity :
  *
- tropical            (uh2o=4.12g/cm2,uo3
  =.247cm-atm)            *
  *
  *
- aerosols type identity :
  *
- no aerosols computed
  *
  *
  *
- spectral condition
  *
- ------------------
  *
- constant
  *
- value of filter function :
  *
- wl inf=27640754752056197120.000 mic   wl
  sup=    0.000 mic   *
  *
  *
- target type
  *
- -----------
  *
- homogeneous ground
  *
- constant reflectance over the spectra
  0.000                 *
  *
  *
- target elevation description
  *
- ----------------------------
  *
- ground pressure  [mb]        862.22
  *
- ground altitude  [km]        1.408
  *
- gaseous content at target level:
  *
- uh2o=    2.056 g/cm2        uo3=    0.244
  cm-atm             *
  *
  *
- atmospheric correction activated
  *
- --------------------------------
  *
  Atmospheric correction...
  Atmospheric correction complete.
  (Fri Dec  6 12:16:10 2013) Command finished (22 sec)

**And here is a description of the output:**

| Layer:    P1toar_atcorrB1@Charlie        Date: Fri Dec  6 12:12:58 2013    |
 | Mapset:   Charlie                        Login of Creator: charlottewhitha |
 | Location: NGH                                                              |
 | DataBase: /Users/charlottewhitham/Documents/PhD/My research/my GIS/grassda |
 | Title:     ( P1toar_atcorrB1 )                                             |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    CELL                                                       |
 |   Rows:         7381                                                       |
 |   Columns:      7551                                                       |
 |   Total Cells:  55733931                                                   |
 |        Projection: UTM (zone 47)                                           |
 |            N:    2666715    S:    2445285   Res:    30                     |
 |            E:     522315    W:     295785   Res:    30                     |
 |   Range of data:    min = NULL  max = NULL                                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    generated by i.atcorr                                                   |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |    i.atcorr -a iimg="Part1toar_B1@Charlie" iscl=0,255 icnd="/Users/char\   |
 |    lottewhitham/Documents/PhD/My research/my GIS/grassdata/NGH/Charlie/\   |
 |    icnd_lsat1.rtf" oimg="P1toar_atcorrB1" oscl=0,255

As you can see the range of data is NULL to NULL... not good.

Comment: Have you set  an appropriate region ?

Comment: Yes, the region is set using the raster layers I'm trying to correct....

Comment: Landsat8 is not yet supported - someone needs to get and properly format the spectral curves, following http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Atmospheric_correction#How_to_add_new_sensors_to_i.atcorr

Comment: This is not true anymore. `i.atcorr` supports for Landsat8 imagery.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I think it should be possible for you to craft an answer of a few sentences to say basically what you have commented.  By providing an answer you can potentially earn reputation and also help the asker and future readers better understand the historical nature of the question and currency of your answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo Apologies for the delay, I've answered the question.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to this @NikosAlexandris - I've upvoted your answer accordingly - just one upvote is enough to take this off the Unanswered list but I hope the asker will Accept and/or Upvote too.  Note that it is only the asker who can Accept an answer.

Comment: Of course, only the original poster can accept an answer. Given the "historical" character of this one, perhaps it is wise to close it, if the OP won't take further action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this question was submitted, there was no support for the recent sensor of the Landsat family.

However, according to [http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/changeset/61314](http://changeset%2061314), wihch is GRASS GIS' official project management system, the [i.atcorr](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/i.atcorr.html) module in [GRASS 7](http://grass.osgeo.org/news/42/15/GRASS-GIS-7-0-0/),  supports for Landsat8 imagery since end of July 2014.

Comment: Herewith, I kindly ask for to either accept this answer, or close this question if the original poster does not act upon within some reasonable time (given that this is an old question and the poster has no interest any more).

Comment: Thank you @Nikos Alexandris. I have accepted your answer and thank you for your time with this - I really appreciate it.